# Restrict security authentication for read access

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I created a web application using a sample project in GitHub. However, it required authentication for all crud operations. I want to restrict this security checking for all read DB operations. What changes do I need?

These are the related classes:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know there is no way to magically create a read only user.However, you can create a role such as `ROLE_UPDATE`  and make all of your methods that perform creates/updates/deletes be secured via `@Secured("ROLE_UPDATE")`.  Then, if a user is not granted the `ROLE_UPDATE` authority, they will not be able to call any of the 'writing' methods, and therefore it will be restricted to only call 'read' methods.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Spring Security doesn't have such feature. You can do as @Alien suggested create some role (ex. `ROLE_WRITE` and then check on the resources if the user who is trying to access the resource has the correct role

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_WRITE')")
public String someWriteOperation() {
}
```

The other way (but it's only applying when your JPA framework allows you such feature) it's create a `Filter` in spring and then before processing your request further in the chain create transaction read-only:

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class TransactionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilterServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        //Create read only transaction  
        // ex. if(isUserReadOnly(Security ....getUser())) {DBSession.setReadOnly(true);}
        //Remember it will work only if your JPA framework have the feature - explore your code/framework before

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Remember filter order should be after Spring Security Filter